# when implementing interfaces get same interface as superclass

Tags: java

in java i am using `generics` and in class i want to use `implements interface(? extends class)` and this interface is `generic interface<T>` but i get message as

```
same interface as superclass
```

code example:

```
public interface ISomething<T>
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string GetType(T t);
}

public class SomeClass implements ISomething<T extends SomeClass2>
```

is this possible?

Comment: please provide some code snippet.

Comment: Can you post the actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a generic specifier that is not defined. In your example for `SomeClass`, `T` is not declared.

This is invalid:

```
public class SomeClass implements ISomething<T extends SomeClass2>
```

Either of these are valid

```
public class SomeClass<T extends SomeClass2> implements ISomething<T>
```

or

```
public class SomeClass implements ISomething<SomeClass2>
```